# Python: compare rows from csv and group together identical results for pdf layout comparison

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pdf

I am trying to find a way to compare the layout of different pdf files. Using tesseract, I am able to export to a CSV file the following data of specific keywords.

Consider this generated csv file with the following content, displaying the left and top coordinates of each keyword, as well as the keyword and the file name:

```
Left,Top,Text,File
118,174,INVOICE,file0
117,333,INVOICE,file0
119,525,BILLED,file0
119,1554,INVOICE,file0
322,1880,invoice,file0
118,174,INVOICE,file1
117,333,INVOICE,file1
119,525,BILLED,file1
119,1554,INVOICE,file1
322,1880,invoice,file1
1112,185,Invoice,file2
113,219,Invoice,file2
1112,212,Invoice,file3
113,219,Invoice,file3
113,217,Invoice,file3
118,174,INVOICE,file4
117,333,INVOICE,file4
119,525,BILLED,file4
119,1554,INVOICE,file4
322,1884,invoice,file4
```

My initial idea is to concatenate the first 3 columns and compare them to the other rows. I am able to obtain which files match for each keyword. But I am unable to obtain which files have an overall matching layout of more than 80% for example.

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
```

Loop over csv to get position and text of keywords

```
with open('data.csv') as file:
    results = []
    file_names = []
    for row in file:
        columns = row.split(',')
        data = columns[0] + columns[1] + columns[2]
        file_name = columns[3].rstrip()
        results = results + [data]
        file_names.append(file_name)
```

Get and print indices of the matches

```
indices = [] 
for a, b in itertools.combinations(results, 2):
    if a == b:
        indices = indices + [[i -1 for i, x in enumerate(results) if x == a]]
print("Indices: ", indices)
```

Print:

```
Indices:  [[0, 5, 15], [0, 5, 15], [1, 6, 16], [1, 6, 16], [2, 7, 17], [2, 7, 17], [3, 8, 18], [3, 8, 18], [4, 9], [0, 5, 15], [1, 6, 16], [2, 7, 17], [3, 8, 18], [11, 13]]
```

Get and print filenames with match

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',')
identical_files = []
for indice in indices:
    file_matches = []
    for i in indice:
        file_matches.append(dataset.iloc[i, -1])
    identical_files.append(file_matches)
print("Identical files: ", identical_files)
```

Print:

```
Identical files:  [['file0', 'file1', 'file4'], ['file0', 'file1', 'file4'], ['file0', 'file1', 'file4'], ['file0', 'file1', 'file4'], ['file0', 'file1', 'file4'], ['file0', 'file1', 'file4'], ['file0', 'file1', 'file4'], ['file0', 'file1', 'file4'], ['file0', 'file1'], ['file0', 'file1', 'file4'], ['file0', 'file1', 'file4'], ['file0', 'file1', 'file4'], ['file0', 'file1', 'file4'], ['file2', 'file3']]
```

So I am able to print the identical files, however, after many attempts I am struggling to figure out the logic to identify which files have an identical layout and should, therefore, be grouped together.

Based on this data, the **output** should be something like this:

```
[
  [file0, file1, file4],
  [file2, file3]
]
```

I am still new to Python so I hope I have made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you need, but try this:

```
res = (df.groupby(by=['Left', 'Top', 'Text'])
       .agg(files = pd.NamedAgg(column="File", aggfunc=', '.join)))
print(res)
```

This will give me

```
                                 files
Left Top  Text                        
1112 185  Invoice                file2
     212  Invoice                file3
113  217  Invoice                file3
     219  Invoice         file2, file3
117  333  INVOICE  file0, file1, file4
118  174  INVOICE  file0, file1, file4
119  1554 INVOICE  file0, file1, file4
     525  BILLED   file0, file1, file4
322  1880 invoice         file0, file1
     1884 invoice                file4
```

which are for all combinatiosn of "Left", "Top", and "Text" the files which have the same combinations.

Does that help?

Comment: Wow, that helps a lot thanks. It's way shorter than my solution. But how would I then determine that file0, file1, and file4 have an identical/very similar layout?

Comment: Hmm, you have to define what "identical" or "very similar" layout means. Then you can find a rule how to find those cases.
In this case it say that file0, file1 and file4 have three features which are identical, file0 and file1 only have 1, etc.